# I am getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while reading a file in folder created after saving voices through multer

Tags: python, node.js, multer

I uploaded audios through client-side in react and using multer saved those files in a folder "public/uploads" on the server-side. Then based on those audios I want to train a model for speaker recognition. In that `training_model.py` python script I am giving path to the folder "public/uploads" where audios were saved for training model but its giving:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. 
All the paths to that folder are saved in a text file named `signupVoices.txt`. I have tried using `os.access()` to see the permissions and it returned true. Tried changing permissions of the folder and also running script as an administrator. The txt files containing paths is also successfully read.

training_model.py:

```py
#import SpeechRecognition as sr
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
# from sklearn.mixture import GMM
from feature_extraction import extract_features
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#path to training data
source   = "public/uploads"  
print( os.access('public/uploads', os.R_OK))
#path where training speakers will be saved
dest = "speaker_models/"
train_file = "signupVoices.txt"
for files in os.listdir("./public/uploads"):
  print (files)
file_paths = open(train_file,'r')

count = 1
# Extracting features for each speaker (5 files per speakers)
features = np.asarray(())
for path in file_paths:

    path = path.strip()
    path = path.replace('\\','/')
    print(source+path)
    # read the audio

    sr,audio = read(source+path)

#    sr = read(source + path)

    # extract 40 dimensional MFCC & delta MFCC features
    vector   = extract_features(audio,sr)

    if features.size == 0:
        features = vector
    else:
        features = np.vstack((features, vector))
    # when features of 5 files of speaker are concatenated, then do model training
    if count == 5:
        gmm = GMM(n_components = 16, max_iter = 200, covariance_type='diag',n_init = 3)
        gmm.fit(features)

        # dumping the trained gaussian model
        picklefile = path.split("-")[0]+".gmm"
        pickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'wb'))
        print('+ modeling completed for speaker:',picklefile," with data point = ",features.shape)
        features = np.asarray(())
        count = 0
    count = count + 1
```

P.S. I am a beginner in machine learning

Comment: A few things: Use context managers to handle file objects. In this case, pathlib is likely better than the os module for path-related operations. Why the `features = np.asarray(())` ?

Comment: Windows will give you a permission-denied error if you attempt to open a directory as if it were a file.  Are you sure that all lines in your `signupVoices.txt` file point to files, not directories?  Also, are you sure there are no blank lines in this file?  Blank lines will cause your code to attempt to open the `source` directory.

Comment: Yes, you are right the problem was in that file. It did contain blank lines. I removed them and it worked. Thank you